# different behavior when a std::string variable is global

Tags: c++, string, sockets

I'm trying to send a string through socket

```
while (getline(cin, cmdline)) {
    const char *temp = cmdline.c_str();
    auto n = send(connfd, temp, MAXTEXT, 0) ;
    cout << n << endl;
```

when cmdline is a global variable, n will be -1.

the error is "Bad address"

when I put cmdline in the first line of main, the socket worked fine.

Weird thing, if i use debug instead of run the exe, it worked fine too.

```
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
```

The whole code can be found here [code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QYDhbW6zmj/)

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us, or it's going to be very hard to debug the issue.

Comment: By the way, when `send` returns `-1`, what is the error? Try printing `errno` (for example using `perror("send failed")`)

Comment: Are you sure the string is initialized before you try to use it?

Comment: Something somewhere in your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: `MAXTEXT` -> `cmdline.size()`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  sorry about that, an example can be found here [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QYDhbW6zmj/)

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* as you tell `send` to go out of bounds of the string you provide. And you really need to add more error checking and print the actual errors you get (`errno`, with the help of `perror` or `strerror`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the error is "Bad address"; why is cmdline out of bounds, isn't it global?

Comment: *send(sockfd, cmdline.c_str(), **4096**, 0)* ... How many characters is there in the string `cmdline`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude just a few, couldn't be more than 4096

Comment: If it is less than 4096, it is also wrong. `send()` will try to read 4096 bytes anyway and as a result it will read through unallocated memory.

Comment: As said, the `send` function doesn't actually know how many bytes it has to send, it only uses the size argument you provide. If you then give it the wrong size, it will happily go out of bounds to attempt to fetch data from memory that isn't owned by your program. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I get it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, by passing 4096 you make `send()` read out of bounds of `cmdline` string. You should use the size of the string or, if you still want to have the limit in place, use minimum of the size and the limit, e.g.:

```cpp
int sendSize = std::min<size_t>(cmdline.size(), 4096);
auto n = send(sockfd, cmdline.c_str(), sendSize, 0);
```

You also have a problem on the server side because your `buf` may not be `\0` terminated. To fix that you could:

```cpp
constexpr int MAX_SIZE = 4096;
char buf[MAX_SIZE + 1];   // +1 for terminating '\0' character
// set the first character to '\0' in case we do not receive anything
buf[0] = '\0';
// or in a single line:
// char buf[MAX_SIZE + 1]{ '\0' };

...

n = recv(connfd, buf, MAX_SIZE, 0);
if (n >= 0) {
    buf[n+1] = '\0';
}
```